# How to integrate intercom live chat feature into an Android app

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, livechat, intercom

I'm try to integrate intercom live chat feature into my app, the live chart platform shows as below but could not load the chart features.

[image]

Also, I get this error in the logcat:

`E/Intercom: Api call failed: {“type”:“error.list”,“request_id”:“0009rulecss011cdfe60",“errors”:[{“code”:“token_not_found”,“message”:“Unauthorized”}]}`

Here are my implementations so far:

```
class App : MultiDexApplication() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        initIntercom()
    }

    private fun initIntercom(){
        Intercom.initialize(this, getString(R.string.intercom_api_key), getString(R.string.intercom_app_id))
    }
}
```

The fragment where I want to open the chat

```
class IntercomLiveChatFragment : Fragment() {

    private val USER_ID = "123456"
    private val CLIENT_ID = "client-id"
    private val SECRET_ID = "secret-id"

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // If you use Identity Verification you will need to include HMAC
    // We suggest taking these values from your app. You may need to change USER_ID above to match your HMAC
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private val YOUR_HMAC = ""

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.intercom_live_chat_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //Enable a user wit Intercom
        Intercom.client().setLauncherVisibility(Intercom.Visibility.VISIBLE)
        //Register a user with Intercom
        Intercom.client().registerIdentifiedUser(Registration.create().withUserId(SECRET_ID))
 
        Intercom.client().updateUser(userAttributes)
        Intercom.client().displayMessenger()
    }

}
```

I passed CLIENT_ID as well for the `withUserId(CLIENT_ID)` but still getting the same error. I am yet to know what exactly is the UserId add if that is what is causing the error. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.intercom.com/installing-intercom/docs/android-identity-verification As it appears here in the official docs, if you log in with Identified user, you also need to provide the hash:

```
Intercom.client().setUserHash("your_hmac_of_user_id_or_email");
```